# Getting weird result as last element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a[5], b[5], sum[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
        sum[i] += a[i] + b[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << sum[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to add the sum of a[i] + b[i] into the sum[i] and then output it. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to work as expected, it outputs some weird value for any number on the last element, here's one example:

```
5.2 1.2
5.3 2.1
2.7 5.3
2.7 5.3
2.6 1.9
6.4 7.4 8 8 7.5784e+268
```

As you can see, the last element is not calculated correctly. I tried using Debugger in C::B and it says everything is fine.

```
Program exited normally.
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: You didn't initialise the values of the sum array

Comment: You didn't throw away newlines. Don't you need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the values in the sum array are not all initialised initially to 0. So you have some garbage value sitting in one of the index of the array which is why your last value is incorrect.

In main do this:

```
sum[5] = {0.0};
```

Also since this has a c++ tag, why not use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? This is because vector will initialise the contents to the default value.

```
std::vector<double> sum(5); //This will contain {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but why doesn't it work for the last element particularly and it works for the rest?

Comment: @user3002211 it is undefined behavior to use an unintialized variable so anything can happen.

Comment: @user3002211: Pure chance. Stack grows down and only one byte in the frame was previously used? Could be anything...

Comment: @user3002211 This might be compiler dependent. i.e. some compilers might initialise some of the values to 0 and not all of them. In any case, don't expect to get any correct result if you have not initialised the array to contain all zeros